# Trying to convert a "not in" statement to a "not exists" -- I've looked at related questions but still can't get it to work

Tags: t-sql

I've got a simple query my ex-boss left me with.  It's using a not in which takes an ENORMOUS amount of time (and for reasons yet to be determined have caused a failover on a server only running one database).  I've tried to change it to a not exists and I'm getting 0 records returned.  I realize it has to be something simple but there is absolutely no one here who has a clue what I'm talking about.

Here's the query:

```
declare @Callback table (ProspectRelationCode varchar(1), CallbackAvail int)
insert into @Callback

select
opp.ppc as ProspectRelationCode,
sum(case when dl.Category = 'Refusal' 
    then 1 else 0
end) as CallbackAvail

from CallResult cr
join Opportunity opp
on opp.id = cr.ID
join dbo.DispositionLookup dl
on dl.lookupkey = cr.CallStatus
where dl.Category = 'Refusal' and opp.Assignment not in (
select Assignment from CallResult cr 
join Opportunity opp
on opp.id = cr.ID
where cr.CallStatus in ('VVOL','RVOL')  )
and  opp.listid >= 1400
group by opp.ppc
```

Here is my (slight) rework:

```
select
    opp.ppc as ProspectRelationCode,
    sum(case when dl.Category = 'Refusal' 
        then 1 else 0
    end) as CallbackAvail

from CallResult cr
join Opportunity opp
    on opp.id = cr.ID
join dbo.DispositionLookup dl
    on dl.lookupkey = cr.CallStatus
where dl.Category = 'Refusal' and not exists  ( select opp.assignment
from  CallResult cr join Opportunity on cr.id = opp.id 
where cr.CallStatus in ('VVOL','RVOL')  )
and  opp.listid >= 1400
group by opp.ppc
```

This is probably a piece of cake for most but I'm hitting a brick wall here.  I'd appreciate any help whatsoever (and I'm prepared for any yelling at me also).

Thank you!
Diane

Answer (score 1):

There's need for the subquery because it joins the data in the same way as your first join statement. Since it was data NOT IN subquery. I move your subquery's WHERE clause and negate it like so:

```
DECLARE @Callback TABLE (
    ProspectRelationCode VARCHAR(1)
    ,CallbackAvail INT
    )

INSERT INTO @Callback
SELECT opp.ppc AS ProspectRelationCode
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN dl.Category = 'Refusal'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS CallbackAvail
FROM CallResult cr
INNER JOIN Opportunity opp ON opp.id = cr.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.DispositionLookup dl ON dl.lookupkey = cr.CallStatus
WHERE   dl.Category = 'Refusal'
        AND cr.CallStatus != 'VVOL'
        AND cr.CallStatus != 'RVOL'
        AND opp.listid >= 1400
GROUP BY opp.ppc
```

Comment: You know, I'm starting to wonder if that original not in portion is working.  Your code as well as all my stumbling has come up with different (but both your suggestion and my attempts were the same) answers in the totals than the original code did.  NOW to just convince my user that the original may be incorrect.  Thank you so much for seeing it a different way!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select
    opp.ppc as ProspectRelationCode,
    sum(case when dl.Category = 'Refusal' 
        then 1 else 0
    end) as CallbackAvail

from CallResult cr
join Opportunity opp
    on opp.id = cr.ID
join dbo.DispositionLookup dl
    on dl.lookupkey = cr.CallStatus
where dl.Category = 'Refusal' and not exists  ( select Opportunity.id
from  CallResult cri join Opportunity on cri.id = opp.id 
where cri.CallStatus in ('VVOL','RVOL')  )
and  opp.listid >= 1400
group by opp.ppc
```

Changed the select list in the sub-query, and also an alias for clarity.

Comment: nope, the interior query pulls records but all the code combined bring 0 rows back.  I appreciate it, though!